# What is Proxy component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I heard the term proxy component in React today. After googling I understand that proxy component means reusability. Is that true? If not, can you please explain what it does.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is too broad of a question, and will also be somewhat opinion-based as there's no *official* 'proxy component' in react. In short, it's not a good fit for stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proxy component is essentially a placeholder component that can be rendered to from another component. And what’s really nice about it, is you can tie it right into the render cycle without having to think imperatively. This component basically allows you to two bend your React data flow tree into the DOM tree.

[Source Doc](https://medium.com/@chetcorcos/shindig-react-proxy-component-bb368510aad4)